# Scala / MongoDB - removing duplicate

Tags: mongodb, scala, duplicates, aggregates

I have seen very similar questions with solutions to this problem, but I am unsure how I would incorporate it in to my own query. I'm programming in Scala and using a MongoDB Aggregates "framework".

```
val getItems = Seq (
    Aggregates.lookup(Store...)...

    Aggregates.lookup(Store.STORE_NAME, "relationship.itemID", "uniqueID", "item"), 
    Aggregates.unwind("$item"), 

    // filter duplicates here ?

    Aggregates.lookup(Store.STORE_NAME, "item.content", "ID", "content"), 
    Aggregates.unwind("$content"), 

    Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.include("store", "item", "content")))

)
```

The query returns duplicate objects which is undesirable. I would like to remove these. How could I go about incorporating Aggregates.group and "$addToSet" to do this? Or any other reasonable solution would be great too.

Note: I have to omit some details about the query, so the store lookup aggregate is not there. However, I want to remove the duplicates later in the query so it hopefully shouldn't matter.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks.

**EDIT: 31/ 07/ 2019: 13:47**

I have tried the following:

```
val getItems = Seq (
    Aggregates.lookup(Store...)...

    Aggregates.lookup(Store.STORE_NAME, "relationship.itemID", "uniqueID", "item"),
    Aggregates.unwind("$item"), 

    Aggregates.group("$item.itemID, 
      Accumulators.first("ID", "$ID"),
      Accumulators.first("itemName", "$itemName"),
      Accumulators.addToSet("item", "$item") 
    Aggregates.unwind("$items"), 

    Aggregates.lookup(Store.STORE_NAME, "item.content", "ID", "content"), 
    Aggregates.unwind("$content"), 

    Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.include("store", "items", "content")))
)
```

But my query now returns zero results instead of the duplicate result.

Comment: Have first tried in MongoShell? To first design the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$first` to remove the duplicates.
Suppose I have the following data:

```
[
  {"_id": 1,"item": "ABC","sizes": ["S","M","L"]},
  {"_id": 2,"item": "EFG","sizes": []},
  {"_id": 3, "item": "IJK","sizes": "M" },
  {"_id": 4,"item": "LMN"},
  {"_id": 5,"item": "XYZ","sizes": null
  }
]
```

Now, let's aggregate it using `$first` and `$unwind` and see the difference:

First let's aggregate it using **$first**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: {
      item: 1
    }
  },
  { $group: {
      _id: "$item",firstSize: {$first: "$sizes"}}}
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {"_id": "XYZ","firstSize": null},
  {"_id": "ABC","firstSize": ["S","M","L" ]},
  {"_id": "IJK","firstSize": "M"},
  {"_id": "EFG","firstSize": []},
  {"_id": "LMN","firstSize": null}
]
```

Now, Let's aggregate it using **$unwind**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$sizes"
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {"_id": 1,"item": "ABC","sizes": "S"},
  {"_id": 1,"item": "ABC","sizes": "M"},
  {"_id": 1,"item": "ABC","sizes": "L},
  {"_id": 3,"item": "IJK","sizes": "M"}
]
```

You can see `$first` removes the duplicates where as `$unwind` keeps the duplicates.

**Using $unwind and $first together.**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$sizes"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",firstSize: {$first: "$sizes"}}
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {"_id": "IJK", "firstSize": "M"},
  {"_id": "ABC","firstSize": "S"}
]
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it using Scala Aggregates? E.g. `Aggregates.group("...")`

Comment: E.g. 

`Aggregates.unwind("$item"), 
Aggregates.group("ID: {$item.ID}, item: {$addToSet: $item}")`

This doesn't work, but it's along the lines of what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to do this using your query?

Comment: `Aggregates.group("ID: {$item.ID}, Accumulators.addToSet("$items)) `
`Aggregates.group("ID: {$item.ID}, Accumulators.first("$items))`
I think this should be something like this if you are talking about `com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates`.

Answer (score 0):

`group`  then  `addToSet` is an effective way  to  deal  with your problem !
it  looks  like  this  in mongoshell

```
db.sales.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group:
      {
        _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: "$date"}, year: { $year: "$date" } },
        itemsSold: { $addToSet: "$item" }
      }
      }
    ]
  )
```

in  scala  you can do it like

```
 Aggregates.group("$groupfield", Accumulators.addToSet("fieldName","$expression"))
```

if  you have multiple  field  to group

```
 Aggregates.group(new BasicDBObject().append("fieldAname","$fieldA").append("fieldBname","$fieldB")), Accumulators.addToSet("fieldName","expression"))
```

then  `unwind`

Comment: BasicDBObject does not seem to be available to me to import

Comment: which  dependency  do you  use  ?  the `mongo-scala-driver` or others

Comment: try  use  ``` Aggregates.group(Document("fieldname" ->"value"),Accumulators.addToSet(....)) ```  is in the `import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.mutable.Document`

Comment: the BasicDBObject   is in ` mongodb-driver-core`  in 
 the  `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject`package